# Conditional Statement If-else

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm building my first application in Django and I am having trouble with the conditional loop. I want to create a form where users would input their name, family size and income and it would calculate where they land on the sliding scale (A, B, C or Overqualify) based on their income. I'm expecting it to output one scale (A,B,C, or Overqualify) but it keeps looping - so what I am getting is:

[What I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x22Fz.png)

If anyone can help me or point me to any resources because I just started learning python and django so I'm quite stuck.

Thank you!

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class SlidingScale(models.Model):
    scale = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    family_size = models.IntegerField()
    min_annual = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    max_annual = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.scale
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class SlidingForm(forms.Form):
   name = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
   household = forms.IntegerField()
   income = forms.IntegerField()
```

**views.py**

```
 from django.shortcuts import render 
    from django.template.response import TemplateResponse 
    from .models import SlidingScale 
    from .forms import SlidingForm

# Create your views here. def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})


def calculator(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        #Get the posted form
        form = SlidingForm(request.POST)
        data = SlidingScale.objects.all()

        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            household = form.cleaned_data['household']
            income = form.cleaned_data['income']
    else:
        form = SlidingForm()

    return render(request, 'result.html', {"name" : name, "household": household, "income":income, "data": data})
```

**result.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

<!--start title -->
{% block title%}
  Result
{% endblock %}

<!-- start body -->
{% block content%}
      <strong>{{ name }}</strong>, based on your income of <strong>{{income}}</strong> and household size of
      <strong>{{household}}</strong>,

      {% for i in data %}
        {% if i.family_size == household and income >= i.min_annual and income <= i.max_annual %}
          <p> You qualify for: {{ i.scale }} </p>
        {% else %}
          <p> You overqualify </p>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}



{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This is not Jinja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want a loop here at all. You want to get the right item from the database to begin with.

```
if form.is_valid():
    name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    household = form.cleaned_data['household']
    income = form.cleaned_data['income']
    scale = SlidingScale.objects.filter(
        family_size=household, min_annual__lte=income, max_annual__gte=income
    ).first()
    return render(request, 'result.html',
        {"name" : name, "household": household, "income":income, "scale": scale}
    )
```

And in the template:

```
  <strong>{{ name }}</strong>, based on your income of <strong>{{income}}</strong> and household size of
  <strong>{{household}}</strong>,

  {% if scale %}
      <p> You qualify for: {{ scale.scale }} </p>
  {% else %}
      <p> You overqualify </p>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: My understanding of pulling data out of the database was murky. I re-read the Django documentation and understood it much better now. Thank you so much for your help!